# Changing excel pivot lay-out to one-dimensional dataset, using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, transpose

My dataset looks like this:

```
   Item Type  Price 1  Price 2  Price 3
      1    A      400      200      -46
      1    B      500      250      -62
      1    C      600      300        0
```

I manage to concat the first 2 columns, but want the dataset to look like this:

```
  Unique_Items variable  value
           1 A  Price 1    400
           1 B  Price 1    500
           1 C  Price 1    600
           1 A  Price 2    200
           1 B  Price 2    250
           1 C  Price 2    300
           1 A  Price 3    -46
           1 B  Price 3    -62
           1 C  Price 3      0
```

How do I transpose column names as row values, and have a new column with the actual prices?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.Series.str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) 
to join the `Item` and `Type` columns .

```
df['Unique_Items']=df['Item'].astype(str).str.cat(df['Type'],sep=' ')
```

Then use [DataFrame.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) 
to get the desired dataframe:

```
df=df[['Unique_Items','Price 1','Price 2','Price 3']].melt('Unique_Items')
print(df)

  Unique_Items variable  value
0          1 A  Price 1    400
1          1 B  Price 1    500
2          1 C  Price 1    600
3          1 A  Price 2    200
4          1 B  Price 2    250
5          1 C  Price 2    300
6          1 A  Price 3    -46
7          1 B  Price 3    -62
8          1 C  Price 3      0
```